# How to pass GET param in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to achieve
/index.php/myapp?id=1

in codeigniter format
like

/index.php/myapp/id/1

But the above doesn't work

Thanks!

UPDATE per comment:

URL=/index.php/myapp/show/1

function show(){
$data=$this->input->get();
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CodeIgniter uses controllers and URL segments to achieve this. With [URI Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html) you will be able to access the ID with `$this->uri->segment(3)`.

You can remove `/id/` from your address and make a kind of RESTful scheme that will redirect `/:any/:num` to `/:any/show/:num`. This way, you'll just have to create a `show` method in your controller to get the ID and process it.

Comment: Codeigniter: Note: This URI class is initialized automatically by the system so there is no need to do it manually...This is the only thing I'm doing to get the GET data $data= $this->input->get();

Comment: I'm added some code based on my understanding of your comment...however, $data is still empty.

Comment: What about `$this->uri->segment(3)` ?

Comment: Yes. it works. But there is a build-in input->get()...how do I use this then?

Comment: You wrote `$data=$this->input->get();`. Do you at least output that variable ? :)

Comment: function show(){ $data=$this->input->get(); echo var_dump($data)}...this output "false" according to CI, which means empty....if I replace with your code, it output 1

Comment: You can't have any data in `$this->input->get()` with the url you gave because paths are interpreted as segments by CodeIgniter. So if you want the ID, just use `$this->uri->segment(3)`.

Comment: Thanks...that's why I read GET is disallowed by default in CI